# Why am I getting this Attribute error when there is data there?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working through [this NewBoston tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=up5Xehmtn2E&index=36&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAcbMi1sH6oAMk4JHw91mC_)  to make a word-frequency calculator. It first grabs text from a web page, then cleans it up and counts the words. I am at the first stage, scraping the text off the page:

```
def start(url):
    word_list = []
    source_code = requests.get(url, verify=True).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)

    for page_text in soup.find_all('p'):
        content = page_text.string
        print(content)
        words = content.lower().split()
        for each_word in words:
            word_list.append(each_word)
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/NewBostonTuts/WordFrequency.py", line 30, in <module>
    start('https://www.example.com')
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/NewBostonTuts/WordFrequency.py", line 13, in start
    words = content.lower().split()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

This suggests to me that it's not getting any `content` to work with, but as you can see I print out `content` before trying to `lower()` and `split()` it and it outputs as expected - all the `<p>` tag contents are displayed.

What gives?

Comment: There must be some values for content which are NoneType.. Try words = content.lower().split() if content else []

Comment: @Alan, but if `content` is sometimes NoneType, why doesn't `print(content)` ever print `None`?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. I'm new to python myself. I guess the question is, is an empty string: '', NoneType? Because if you print an empty string, nothing will show.

Comment: No, an empty string is not a NoneType. It's a string and it's perfectly valid to call `lower()` on it.

Comment: @user4676723 I tried your code using `"http://www.example.com"` as the url and it worked perfectly. What url are you using that's producing this error?

Comment: Ah ha. Just pored over the output of `print(content)` and it does at one point output 'None'. What would cause that?

Comment: @user4676723 try to specify parser BeautifulSoup is supposed to use:
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "html.parser")
Maybe that'll help

Comment: @vrs no luck I'm afraid

Comment: @user4676723 try guarding against NoneType with something like `if content: ...` or `try/except` and see, how your result will differ from the expected one for `https://www.example.com`. My word_list looks like this: ['this', 'domain', 'is', 'established', 'to', 'be', 'used', 'for', 'illustrative', 'examples', 'in', 'documents.', 'you', 'may', 'use', 'this', 'domain', 'in', 'examples', 'without', 'prior', 'coordination', 'or', 'asking', 'for', 'permission.', 'more', 'information...']

Comment: Does using `page_text.text` instead solve your problem?

Comment: @DanielF Yes! That works. If you want to make it an answer I will go ahead and accept.

Comment: use content = page_text.contents instead to get the actual value in the p tag

Answer (score 0):

Use `tag.text` instead of `tag.string`. `tag.string` is a [NavigableString](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) and can be of type `NoneType` if the tag contains no text, while `tag.text` in that case contains a string of length 0.

**tag.string**

> Convenience property to get the single string within this tag.
>
> :Return: If this tag has a single string child, return value is that
>   string. If this tag has no children, or more than one child, return
>   value is None. If this tag has one child tag, return value is the
>   'string' attribute of the child tag, recursively.

This is the implementation of that property

```
if len(self.contents) != 1:
    return None
child = self.contents[0]
if isinstance(child, NavigableString):
    return child
return child.string
```

**tag.text**

I have no idea how this variable gets populated. I *think* it comes from the use of [lxml](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) or [html5lib](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python).

Comment: Ok but why does it say `NoneType object has no attribute...` instead of `NavigableString object has no attribute...`?

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 2.7.4:

```
>>> a=None
>>> print(a)
None
>>> a.lower()
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Even though a is None, print will convert it using str(), which is why the call to print() doesn't fail:

```
>>> a
>>> str(a)
'None'
```

If we dig deeper, the None type has **str** defined, which is what is invoked by  str() during the call to print():

```
>>> dir(None)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```